# Typescript constructor generic argument inference

Tags: typescript, type-inference

i'm trying to type a nested nested serializer hierarchy. this snippet below is a simplified version of what we have:

```
'use strict';

abstract class TypedSerializer<In, Out> {

  record: In;

  constructor(record: In) {
    this.record = record;
  }

  serializeObject<PIn, POut, S extends ObjectSerializerConstructor<PIn, POut>>(ctor: S, data: PIn): POut {
    const serializerInstance = new ctor(data);
    return serializerInstance.toObject();
  }

  serializeArray<PIn, POut, S extends ObjectSerializerConstructor<PIn, POut>>(ctor: S, arr: PIn[]): POut[] {
    const fn: ((PIn) => POut) = data => this.serializeObject(ctor, data);
    return arr.map(fn);
  }
}

type ObjectSerializerConstructor<In, Out> = {
  new(record: In): ObjectSerializer<In, Out>;
};

abstract class ObjectSerializer<In, Out> extends TypedSerializer<In, Out> {

  toObject(): Out {
    return null as Out;
  }
}

abstract class TypedListSerializer<In, Out> extends TypedSerializer<In, Out> {
  toList(): Out[] {
    return [] as Out[];
  }
}

interface A {
  prop1: string;
}

interface B {
  prop2: string;
}

class RecordSerializer extends ObjectSerializer<A, B> implements B {

  get prop2() {
    return '';
  }
}

interface ListOut {
  arr: B[]
}

class TestListSerializer extends TypedListSerializer<A, ListOut> implements ListOut {
  produceInputs(): A[] {
    return [] as A[];
  }

  get arr() { // <-- fails here, line 63
    return this.serializeArray(RecordSerializer, this.produceInputs());
  }
}
```

i'm expecting it to compile just fine, but it produces an error:

```
tsc --moduleResolution node --target es6 --lib es6 --noEmit true test.ts 
test.ts(63,7): error TS2416: Property 'arr' in type 'TestListSerializer' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'ListOut'.
  Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'B[]'.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'B'.
      Property 'prop2' is missing in type '{}'.
```

here's [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src='use%20strict'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20TypedSerializer%3CIn%2C%20Out%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20record%3A%20In%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(record%3A%20In)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.record%20%3D%20record%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20serializeObject%3CPIn%2C%20POut%2C%20S%20extends%20ObjectSerializerConstructor%3CPIn%2C%20POut%3E%3E(ctor%3A%20S%2C%20data%3A%20PIn)%3A%20POut%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20serializerInstance%20%3D%20new%20ctor(data)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20serializerInstance.toObject()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20serializeArray%3CPIn%2C%20POut%2C%20S%20extends%20ObjectSerializerConstructor%3CPIn%2C%20POut%3E%3E(ctor%3A%20S%2C%20arr%3A%20PIn%5B%5D)%3A%20POut%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20fn%3A%20((PIn)%20%3D%3E%20POut)%20%3D%20data%20%3D%3E%20this.serializeObject(ctor%2C%20data)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20arr.map(fn)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ObjectSerializerConstructor%3CIn%2C%20Out%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20new(record%3A%20In)%3A%20ObjectSerializer%3CIn%2C%20Out%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20ObjectSerializer%3CIn%2C%20Out%3E%20extends%20TypedSerializer%3CIn%2C%20Out%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20toObject()%3A%20Out%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%20as%20Out%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20TypedListSerializer%3CIn%2C%20Out%3E%20extends%20TypedSerializer%3CIn%2C%20Out%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20toList()%3A%20Out%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%20as%20Out%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20prop1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20prop2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20RecordSerializer%20extends%20ObjectSerializer%3CA%2C%20B%3E%20implements%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20get%20prop2()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ListOut%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20arr%3A%20B%5B%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TestListSerializer%20extends%20TypedListSerializer%3CA%2C%20ListOut%3E%20implements%20ListOut%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20produceInputs()%3A%20A%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%20as%20A%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20get%20arr()%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20fails%20here%2C%20line%2063%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.serializeArray(RecordSerializer%2C%20this.produceInputs())%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) to typescript playground

to me it looks like TSC fails to properly infer actual generic arguments of `RecordSerializer`, so it ends up with an array of `{}` instead an array of `B`.

adding explicit cast like `this.serializeArray(...) as B[]` fixes the problem.
but there must be a better way to tell Typescript what i want. what am i missing?

i'm using v2.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting typescript to infer one generic parameter based on another does not usually work very well. The simplest solution is to use conditional types to extract the in and out paramteres based on `S`

```
type GetInFrom<T> = T extends ObjectSerializerConstructor<infer In, any>? In : never; 
type GetOutFrom<T> = T extends ObjectSerializerConstructor<any, infer Out>? Out : never;

serializeObject<S extends ObjectSerializerConstructor<any, any>>(ctor: S, data: GetInFrom<S>): GetOutFrom<S> {
    const serializerInstance = new ctor(data);
    return serializerInstance.toObject();
}

serializeArray<S extends ObjectSerializerConstructor<any, any>>(ctor: S, arr: GetInFrom<S>[]): GetOutFrom<S>[] {
    const fn: ((pIn: GetInFrom<S>) => GetOutFrom<S>) = (data => this.serializeObject(ctor, data));
    return arr.map(fn);
}
```

Full code on [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20GetInFrom%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20ObjectSerializerConstructor%3Cinfer%20In%2C%20any%3E%3F%20In%20%3A%20never%3B%20%0D%0Atype%20GetOutFrom%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20ObjectSerializerConstructor%3Cany%2C%20infer%20Out%3E%3F%20Out%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20TypedSerializer%3CIn%2C%20Out%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20record%3A%20In%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(record%3A%20In)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.record%20%3D%20record%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20serializeObject%3CS%20extends%20ObjectSerializerConstructor%3Cany%2C%20any%3E%3E(ctor%3A%20S%2C%20data%3A%20GetInFrom%3CS%3E)%3A%20GetOutFrom%3CS%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20serializerInstance%20%3D%20new%20ctor(data)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20serializerInstance.toObject()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20serializeArray%3CS%20extends%20ObjectSerializerConstructor%3Cany%2C%20any%3E%3E(ctor%3A%20S%2C%20arr%3A%20GetInFrom%3CS%3E%5B%5D)%3A%20GetOutFrom%3CS%3E%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20fn%3A%20((pIn%3A%20GetInFrom%3CS%3E)%20%3D%3E%20GetOutFrom%3CS%3E)%20%3D%20(data%20%3D%3E%20this.serializeObject(ctor%2C%20data))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20arr.map(fn)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ObjectSerializerConstructor%3CIn%2C%20Out%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20new(record%3A%20In)%3A%20ObjectSerializer%3CIn%2C%20Out%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20ObjectSerializer%3CIn%2C%20Out%3E%20extends%20TypedSerializer%3CIn%2C%20Out%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20toObject()%3A%20Out%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%20as%20Out%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20TypedListSerializer%3CIn%2C%20Out%3E%20extends%20TypedSerializer%3CIn%2C%20Out%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20toList()%3A%20Out%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%20as%20Out%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20prop1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20prop2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20RecordSerializer%20extends%20ObjectSerializer%3CA%2C%20B%3E%20implements%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20get%20prop2()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ListOut%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20arr%3A%20B%5B%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TestListSerializer%20extends%20TypedListSerializer%3CA%2C%20ListOut%3E%20implements%20ListOut%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20produceInputs()%3A%20A%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%20as%20A%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20get%20arr()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.serializeArray(RecordSerializer%2C%20this.produceInputs())%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: the playground link is broken - it opens to a blank page. i'll play with the code in my IDE.

Comment: @ilj Strange... I will try to fix it when I get to work. The code seems to be there but the playground is ignoring it

Comment: @ilj Fixed the playground link

Comment: a bit weird that using <any> works better than using <T>, but it does work the way i intended. thank you.